# merge some fidAll result and shwo in CGrridView in YII

Tags: php, yii, criteria, cgridview

if I have some findAll result from same model.
but by different criteria.

Can I merge in a variable and use in CArrayDataProvider and send to view and show by CGridView?

```
$model1=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria1);
$model2=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria2);
$model3=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria3);
$data=merge($model1,$model2,$model3);
$provider = new CArrayDataProvider( $data );
        $this->render('list2', array(
            'model' => $provider
        ));
```

Comment: they are simply arrays,use `array_merge()` or `CMap::mergeArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use array_merge function to get the combined array.

Try this -

```
$model1= mymodel::model()->findAll($criteria1);
$model2= mymodel::model()->findAll($criteria2);
$model3= mymodel::model()->findAll($criteria3);
$data= array_merge($model1,$model2,$model3);

$provider = new CArrayDataProvider( $data );
$this->render('list2', array(
              'model' => $provider
           ));
```